# If filter() returns an array why can't we chain splice() on it?

Tags: javascript

This works:

```
const newFilters = filters.filter((filter) => filter !== selectFilter);
newFilters.splice(2, 0, selectFilter);
```

This does't:

```
const newFilters = filters
  .filter((filter) => filter !== selectFilter)
  .splice(2, 0, selectFilter);
```

`newFilters` is an array in either case, so why can't we chain splice to it?

And is there any way to chain it?

Comment: you could use slice in this case

Comment: Could you please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chaining works as expected, but you're probably not getting the results you expect.

This is because [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) modifies the array in place, and returns an array containing the deleted items. In your case, no items are deleted, so `splice()` will return an empty array.

Comment: the chaining works fine, it jus means remove at index 2, 0 items and replace it with `selectFilter`. That returns you an array with the replaced items, in his case its 0, so its an empty array

Comment: @Kaiido I think the actual question is "If filter() returns an array why can't we chain splice() on it and get a modified array?"

Comment: Indeed that's probably what they should have been asking and your edit greatly improves your answer with this regard.

Answer (score 0):

`splice` is a mutative operation which modifies the array in place. It returns the opposite of what you expected, that is the subarray of the items removed from array, not the new array. That's why chaining does not work (while it's good for `filter` as it returns the new array).

Instead of chaining you need to use the result in place as you already found out:

```
let newFilters = filters
   .filter((filter) => filter !== selectFilter)
newFilters.splice(2, 0, selectFilter); // newFilters now is changed, but the result of this expression is not the new array
```